# system recovery in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, recovery

How would you add system recovery in a multi-threaded environment? For eg: if you have a system where multiple threads pickup files and process them and persist them in database, how would the system recover if there is a database failure you 
dont want to process the trades again?

Comment: Depends... Do you wish to retain jobs which are not completed or scrap them?

Comment: A lot of that depends on your situation and there are many strategies. For example: grab file -> log operation as in progress in db -> process and persist -> remove operation from log -> remove file. Include unprocessed files in backup with db backups, just in case. On recovery, reprocess operations that are in log, taking care that your db and code has the ability to overwrite partially persisted data instead of duplicating it. Proper use of transactions and db logging are also useful.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different ways to answer this question depending on your system setup.  A little bit more of an explanation would help.  I have still provided an example that could possibly work for you though.

I would probably look at a way to mark a file as in process (i.e. database record or moving to a different directory to process the file).  Then I would mark the file as finished when it processed (moving it or doing it some other way).

There is a still a possibility of failure after finish processing and marking the file as finished.  However, this would limit the amount of files you need to look at for recovery.

If you can keep track of what files were read in the same database you can batch all your databases changes as well as the flag to mark the file as read.  You can avoid committing the connection until your have done the changes and flagged the file.

This also has an issue of if the database crashes mid commit, but at the same time you would probably have to restore a backup in this instance and rerun all the files again.

Comment: +1 as soon as my vote limit resets; a much better way of saying what I tried to say in my comment.

Comment: If the files are removed after processing, including unprocessed files in a backup sync'd with db backups can make it easier to restore from a backup.